# Does $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx}$, with $x \in [0,1]$, converge uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Does $$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx}, \qquad x \in [0,1]$$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$?

---

I have shown that $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x) \equiv 0$, but I am struggling to prove or disprove uniform convergence.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Note that

$$\frac{x}{1+nx}\le \frac{1}{n}, \forall x\in[0,1],\forall n\in \mathbb{N.}$$

Comment: Thank you! I've done it now :)